# Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'component' of null, when trying to navigate to the same route with different parameters

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-routing

I'm currently working on an Angular (v5.2.5) project, and I'm having some issues with the routing.

Here are my routes:

```
const routes: Routes =[
    { path:'', component: ClassComponent},
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
    { path: ':id', component: ClassComponent}
];
```

Here I have some links that are supposed to match the `:id` path:

```
 <ul>
    <li > 
       <a routerLink='/0000'>
          Emilia 
       </a> 
    </li>

    <li > 
        <a routerLink='/1111'>
            Kit
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now if I click on one of those links everything works fine (I get redirected to `http://localhost:4200/0000` or `http://localhost:4200/1111`) but if one of those links is already selected, and I try clicking on the other one, nothing happens and the following error shows up:

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXrLE.png)

Comment: your scenario works fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7teqls?file=app%2Fsib2.component.html . Can you elaborate more as I think you have something more going on than what I have created in the demo code

Answer (score 1):

Guess this happens due to the fact that it's the same route from the eye of the router. What you could do, even if I think it's not ideal is to set the `onSameUrlNavigation` strategy to reload, but this will apply to all routes not only that one, so I'm pretty sure that there must be another solution to this as well, but in your `AppModule` use

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot( routes, { onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'} )
],
```

Comment: `onSameUrlNavigation` is something new to me +1

Comment: still doesn't work, even if this worked, it isn't what we want, as we don't want the page to reload, otherwise we could use `href` instead, the benefit of using routerLink is that your components don't get destroyed.